# Is there a compile time way to assert a base class is the "first" and at 0 offset from a subclass in C++

Tags: c++

```
class MiClass : public Base1, public Base2 {
  
};

// assuming all base classes have a virtual destructor.
// I want a compile time test to determine if the offset of Base1 in MiClass
// is 0 at compile time so a template will fail to compile if the offset of 
// the base is NOT 0  ie: so in the compile time assert Base1 will be ok 
// but testing Base2 will fail.
// to assert that:

void *vp = xxx; ( assume a valid pointer to an MiClass )

MiClass *mip = reinterpret_cast<MiClass*>(vp);
Base1 *b1p = reinterpret_cast<Base1*>(vp);

such that static_cast<Base1*>(mip) == b1p;
```

Is there a boost template that could be placed in a static assert like:

```
is_single_inherited_subclass_of_base<MiClass,SomeBaseInMiClass>()
```

?

Comment: What you need is `is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of` and as of now, no compiler supports it.